# drawString in loop writes only once instead of multiple times

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

What would this code do?

```
for(int i = 0; i < enemysno; i++){
    g.drawString("\nArray size: " + i, 200, 200);
}
```

enemysno is a random number between 0 and 10, and works fine. Problem is, it loops once, but then stops adding new lines after the first iteration.

As Psuedo code, I though the i starts as 0. Then compares the condition, if its false, does the code, then makes the ++ iterations, then repeats the loop?

Ultimatly, I want to add n objects to an array, but I can quite get this to work simple array to work!

Comment: You should probably use `System.out.println` instead of `g.drawString` at first to focus on the loop problem.

Comment: @dystroy is right: the strings just overwrite each other on the canvas...

Comment: Sorry then, evening!  Thanks for that, made the change, but the loop never stops now! if the random is 4, then is loops 0, 1, 2, 3 then repeats...

Comment: Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: @K.L. why will op try,we are here to solve

Comment: if your first time using this ..then please learn from this kind of things... even your question should be meet the standard so it can be answered...

Comment: @MarounMaroun You just troll me with your link. HUH !!!!

Comment: _then is loops 0, 1, 2, 3 then repeats_ This shouldn't be possible. Maybe problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: [Should have read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thanks for your helps in this one. It was a silly question I know, but now I have created my array of enemies, and they all populate my screen using the for loop. So you guys actually helped alot! The reason it was going wring before, is because my loop was in the render() class. It kept on going! I moved it to the init() class and now its perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple test proves the loop indeed works as intended:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int enemysno = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < enemysno; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("lalala " + i);
        }
    }
```

this works fine producing

```
lalala 0
lalala 1
lalala 2
lalala 3
lalala 4
```

It was kind of obvious, but via debugging or such a test you could determine that the loop itself is entered the desired numer of times. The problem must be in your string display: most probably your drawString method overwrites the printed string each time.

It should be obvious if you checked the numbers on your output.

The solution?

use a string builder to concatenate the partial strings and then draw the final string using your drawString method

Comment: Thanks for your helps in this one. It was a silly question I know, but  now I have created my array of enemies, and they all populate my screen using the for loop.  So you guys actually helped alot! The reason it was going wring before, is because my loop was in the render() class. It kept on going! I moved it to the init() class and now its perfect